# What's wrong with my avl tree add() function?

Tags: c++, avl-tree

It's my first post here. I'm learning avl trees and now trying to write a simple recursion adding function.
I dont know what's wrong with my code. I would be glad for your time to look at my function and tell me what to do.

Class Tree has only one private pointer named root. Class Node has two protected pointers (left and right)

The compiler gives no errors at all which is confusing me more.

```
void add(T toAdd, Node <T> *ptr)
    {
       if(ptr==nullptr) //first ptr is root
        {
            ptr=new Node <T> (toAdd);

            return;
        }

        //everything below is not working. I dont know why
        if(toAdd<ptr->getVal())
        {
            add(toAdd,ptr->left);
        }
        else
        {
            add(toAdd,ptr->right);
        }
    }
```

also after adding some objects my second function named member() which checks if given node exists tells there is nothing in the tree.

member function:

```
bool member(T val)   //check if val node exist
    {
        if(root==nullptr)
        {
            cout<<"tree is empty"<<endl;
            return false;
        }

        Node <T> *current=root;

        while(current)
        {
            if(current->getVal()==val) return true;

            if(val<current->getVal())
            {
                current=current->left;
            }
            else current=current->right;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

improved member function (recursion):

```
bool member(T val, Node <T> *ptr) //recursion
    {
        if(ptr==nullptr)
        {
            cout<<"tree is empty"<<endl;
            return false;
        }
        else if(ptr->getVal()==val)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(val<ptr->getVal()) member(val,ptr->right);
            else member(val,ptr->left);
        }
    }
```

Main function:

```
int main()
{

    Tree <int> avlTree;

    int n,value;

    cin>>n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>value;
        avlTree.add(value,avlTree.getRoot());
    }

    avlTree.member(7);

    return 0;
}
```

getRoot function simply returns root pointer.
Again i would be glad if someone helped me.

Comment: The signature `void add(T toAdd, Node <T> *ptr)` is wrong. `ptr=new Node <T> (toAdd);` does not work as you want because `ptr` is passed by value. The function calling this will not see the change to `ptr`

Comment: Compilers only check the syntax of your program. They have no way of knowing whether it does what you want.

Comment: @drescherjm i've changed member function so that it works as recursion and it works. Now tried to apply those changes to add function and it doesnt work. i've put the code in my post above.